# Erro na função para retornar QueryString em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, url, querystring

Ao utilizar essa função chamando o parâmetro filter da um erro, em vez de retorna o valor do parâmetro da QueryString ele retorna uma function.

```
//Retorna os valores da querystring
function QueryString(pName)
{
    //Cria as variaveis
    var lQueryValue;
    var lQueryString = location.search.replace(/\x3F/, "").replace(/\x2B/g, " ").split("&");
    //Verifica se tem alguma query string
    if (lQueryString != "")
    {
        //Cria o array
        var lArray = [];
        //Roda em todos os caracteres da querystring
        for (var i = 0; i < lQueryString.length; i++)
        {
            //Quebra a query string
            lQueryValue = lQueryString[i].split("=");
            //Seta o valor do array
            lArray[lQueryValue[0]] = unescape(lQueryValue[1]);
        }
        //Armazena o retorno
        var lReturn = lArray[pName];
        //Retorna
        return lReturn;
    }
    return null
}
```

Verifiquei que esse parece ser um problema do array.

```
var lArray = [];
lArray['filter'];
```

Deveria retornar o valor undefined ou o valor correto, mas retorna o string do protótipo da função filter do array.

Alguém tem alguma dica de como resolver esse problema ?

Comment: Está retornando esse valor:

function filter() {[native code]}

Answer (score 0):

Amigo o que está acontecendo é que no seu array `lArray` você está adicionado uma chave e depois está tentando buscar ela com outro nome. Troque a seguinte linha:

```
lArray[lQueryValue[0]] = unescape(lQueryValue[1]);
```

Pela seguinte:

```
lArray[lQueryValue[0].substr(lQueryValue[0].indexOf('?') + 1)] = unescape(lQueryValue[1]);
```

Espero ter ajudado amigo

Comment: Então, mas funciona com todos os parâmetros solicitados na url, só não funciona com quando pergunto pelo parâmetro 'filter'.

Vou tentar aplicar sua sugestão e aviso se tive algum sucesso.

Agradeço a sua análise.

Comment: Troquei a linha como você sugere e o erro permaneceu

Comment: Parece que existe uma função filter nativa no objeto array e por esse motivo ele não entende como pesquisar um valor e sim como uma referência a função filter, por isso retorna o código da função, veja no link

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

Comment: A solução do problema seria tentar fazer ele pesquisar dentro do array pelo valor string filter e não pela referência da função.

Comment: Tenta utilizar o seguinte código:

var lArray = [];
lArray['filter'];

Vai ver que nesse simples trecho o problema ocorre.